# Como funciona a medalha socrático?

Tags: suporte, medalhas

Como funciona a medalha socrático?

> Fazer uma boa pergunta em 100 dias diferentes e manter um histórico de pergunta positiva

Como é medido este boa pergunta? Tenho no meu monitor de medalhas esta medalha com esta estatística (41/100)

Comment: tens de fazer 100 boas perguntas em dias diferentes e manter um histórico de pergunta positiva.

Comment: mas como é medido este `boa pergunta`? é quantidade de votos (quantos ?), números de visitas (quantas ?), numero de respostas (quantas ?)

Comment: Boa pergunta = votação positiva

Comment: sim mas qual a quantidade de votos? tenho 56 perguntas com 1 ou mais votos. e 34 com 2 ou mais

Comment: Não tens nenhuma no meio dessas com negativo? Não te esqueças que tem de ser 100 em dias DIFERENTES

Comment: Negativo umas 5, zero 10.

Comment: Então tens de ver se em 100 dias DIFERENTES tiveste 41 perguntas com 0 ou mais pontos sem nenhuma negativa entretanto...

Comment: Pera ae. Que monitor de medalhas? Onde ele tá mostrando esse 41/100?

Comment: @Math no perfil ta escrito assim acima das medalhas que ja tenho :Próxima medalha socratico 41/10

Comment: É que para mim aparece no seu perfil: "Próxima medalha 79/100 Espírito Esportivo", mas sendo assim, de acordo com esse contador seu você tem 41 perguntas que são elegíveis para a conta da medalha. Só preciso descobrir agora pq a query abaixo retorna 46, pode ser que uma das duas esteja errada ou desatualizada.

Comment: E o que tem a ver a pergunta que você linkou? "Centralizar div container na pagina do Bootstrap"

Comment: quando criei a pergunta achei que era: fazer uma pergunta que fosse boa em 100 dias diferentes, logo julguei que seria esta pergunta minha pois é a que tem mais visitas, excluirei da pergunta

Comment: @RicardoHenrique ah tá, agora entendi

Comment: mas o resultado esta diferente no meu monitor diz que tenho 41/100 na sua query diz 46/100

Comment: Sim, acredito que a query está errada, a query costumava ser feita por usuários na ferramente SEDE quando ainda não existia o recurso do quadro de medalhas, eu diria que se alguém errou foi quem escreveu aquela query e não quem fez o código do quadro de medalhas. Atualizei minha resposta.

Answer (score 4):

Eu diria que esse é mais um caso de descrição ambígua das medalhas do nosso site.

Vou tentar explicar com as minhas palavras e veja se você entende. Para conseguir a medalha você precisa:

Ter feito pelo menos uma pergunta por dia em pelo menos 100 dias distintos. Ao menos uma das perguntas de cada dia deve ter pontuação positiva (>0) e ela não pode estar suspensa ou fechada. A quantidade de visitas e de respostas não importam.

Você pode acompanhar o seu andamento através do seu quadro de medalhas. Caso ela não seja a próxima medalha a ser conseguida sugerida pelo sistema, clique no botão da engrenagem ao lado da barra de status, com a descrição "Escolha qual medalha acompanhar", lá aparecerá várias medalhas e o seu progresso para alcançá-las.

Como você mesmo disse, nesse quadro está indicado 41/100, isso quer dizer que você possui 41 perguntas que atendem os requisitos que eu descrevi acima, você precisa de mais 59 para conseguir a medalha. Não necessariamente você precisa **fazer** mais 59 perguntas, se algumas das que você já tem mas que estão com pontuação de `0` ganharem ao menos um ponto ela e ela for a única positiva daquele dia, ela se torna elegível para a contabilização das perguntas que lhe garantirão uma medalha.

Comment: A [sugestão de tradução](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1660) da época em que a medalha foi criada era um pouco melhor. Quem quer ir arrumar no Transifex?

Comment: Podemos reviver aquele tópico para ver se alguém aparece com alguma sugestão antes de mudarmos no Transifex